# behind a pypi proxy, "no ... working download links" running setup.py

Tags: python-3.x, nexus, setuptools

I'm behind a company pypi proxy (nexus) and I'm having trouble getting dependency resolution in easy_install to work.  Specifically, `python setup.py test` fails because there are no 'working download links'.

I've configured the proxy in a setup.cfg like so:

```
[easy_install]
index-url = https://<hostname>/repository/<mirrorname>/simple
index = https://<hostname>/repository/<mirrorname>/pypi
```

The weird thing is that, for a package named `my_package` that is listed as a dependency in `setup.py`, I see the following lines in the output of `python setup.py test`:

```
Reading https://<hostname>/repository/<mirrorname>/simple/my-package/
Reading https://<hostname>/repository/<mirrorname>/simple/my_package/
```

and if I direct my browser to `https://<hostname>/repository/<mirrorname>/simple/my-package/` I get a basic HTML page with links that look like this:

```
Links for my-package
my-package-0.0.2-py3-none-any.whl
my-package-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
```

I can't find any documentation for how easy_install selects download links and that makes it hard to investigate further.

Installing the same packages using pip works.  This is what my `~/.config/pip/pip.conf` looks like:

```
[global]
index = https://<hostname>/repository/<mirrorname>/pypi
index-url = https://<hostname>/repository/<mirrorname>/simple
```

My Python version is `Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)` (Linux).